# (vectorization) loop through two dataframe cell by cell and find if one is part of the other

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe contains color and material parameters and another one contain data. I want to check cell by cell if the data dataframe have any of the data in the parameters dataframe
I know that I should use vectorization but I am not sure how

```
parameter = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['red','blue','green'],
                   'material': ['wood','metal','plastic']})


data = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['my blue color','red chair','green rod'],
                   'description': ['it is a great color','made with wood','made with metal']})
```

and i want to create a new column contains the parameters. This is the output that i need.

```
data['attribute2']= ['','wood','metal']
print(data)
```

```
           color             material attribute attribute2
0  my blue color  it is a great color      blue           
1      red chair       made with wood       red       wood
2      green rod      made with metal     green      metal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code filters `color` and `material` which is able to extract color(s) and material(s).

```py
data['attribute'] = data['name'].apply(lambda name: ','.join([c for c in parameter['color'].tolist() if c in name]))
data['attribute2'] = data['description'].apply(lambda desc: ','.join([m for m in parameter['material'].tolist() if m in desc]))
```

Output:

| index | color | material | attribute | attribute2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | my blue color | it is a great color | blue |  |
| 1 | red chair | made with wood | red | wood |
| 2 | green rod | made with metal | green | metal |

Comment: can you please re check it. It is name and description